# Is http://zrx.plus a legit site to claim my 0x exchange tokens?

Tags: airdrop, 0x

Is http://zrx.plus/ a legit site to claim my 0x coins? What are some precautions to have before claiming my air drop?

Comment: No it is not legit.

Comment: why? Where is the legit site to claim the coins then?

Comment: If a company does and airdrop or gives away tokens, they will make it very clear on their website, Twitter, subreddit, etc. If you look on those channels for ZRX, you will see no mention of this website.

Comment: where does one go then?

Comment: For what, exactly?